# python - assistance with counting loop

Tags: python

Here is the portion of my code :

```
 if again():
        print ('%s T: %s') % (m, hsh)
        count = 1
        m = 0.001
        amount = m / 0.01
        amount = int(amount)
        print ('Betting %s m') % m
        apply(amount, int(count))
    else:
        print ('%s T: %s') % (m, hsh)
        try:
            count = count * 2
        except:
            count = 1
            count = count * 2

        print count    
        m = 0.001 * count
        amount = m / 0.01
        amount = int(amount)
        print ('K %s m') % m
        apply(amount, int(count))
```

If the function `again()` returns true, part of what it's suppost to do is print count, which is always set to 1 if `again()` is true.

If it returns false, it prints count * 2

If it returned true 3 times, it would print

```
1
1
1
```

If it returned false 3 times, it would print

```
2
4
8
```

However, it just prints

```
2
2
2
```

The try except is for the unassigned variable error if it returns false for the first time.

I do not assign  the variable count or even use it anywhere else.

Comment: Sounds like a scope issue, possibly. Are you trying to use variables that are out of scope?

Comment: All the variables are created there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but `count` should be a global variable, the hack you have with the `try/catch` block is very bad practice and non-standard.

Make `count` a global variable and then you can refactor your `if/else` as a function and just call that:

```
count = 1

# the rest of your code, I'm guessing some loop

def my_function(m, hsh):
    if again():
        print ('%s T: %s') % (m, hsh)
        count = 1
        m = 0.001
        amount = m / 0.01
        amount = int(amount)
        print ('Betting %s m') % m
        apply(amount, int(count))
    else:
        print ('%s T: %s') % (m, hsh)
        count = count * 2
        print count    
        m = 0.001 * count
        amount = m / 0.01
        amount = int(amount)
        print ('K %s m') % m
        apply(amount, int(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `count` outside of your if/else statement.

```
count = 1 #This could be defined outside the method or class and accessed with global


global count
if again():
        print ('%s T: %s') % (m, hsh)
        count = 1 #this will access the count outside the if
        m = 0.001
        amount = m / 0.01
        amount = int(amount)
        print ('Betting %s m') % m
        apply(amount, int(count))
    else:
        print ('%s T: %s') % (m, hsh)
        count = count * 2

        print count    
        m = 0.001 * count
        amount = m / 0.01
        amount = int(amount)
        print ('K %s m') % m
        apply(amount, int(count))
```

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do